# RewriteRule: which regex quantifier are permitted?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, quantifiers

I'd like to know if I can use a quantifier {x} in order to define a RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})-page/?$ /www/page.php?firstId=$1&secondId=$2
```

Can I write something like this?

Thanks for answers

Comment: They should work fine, can you not test it yourself?

Comment: I didn't find anything about it on google, and I can't test because of my society's system of developpement... In fact, I can't test anything yet.
Thank you for your answser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can...

Doesn't it work?

Comment: Should've put mine as an answer...doh! :)